# Norway forest roads tolls by bicycle

Tags: bicycles, norway, tolls

Some forestry roads in Norway are toll roads.  For example, see [here](https://maps.app.goo.gl/Lo7yeE1KS41Mdmc17) or [here on Google Streetview](https://maps.app.goo.gl/AbFsChE7vX2tjTqJ8), [this NRK Trøndelag news article](https://www.nrk.no/trondelag/250-kr-i-bomveiavgift-1.7127827), or [this inatur article](https://info.inatur.no/bomvei).  The signs imaged by Google Streetview mention several vehicle categories, but do not mention bicycles.  Does this mean bicycles are free of charge, or is the list incomplete?

What does it cost to pass on such a road by bicycle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple answer: There are no road tolls for bicycles in Norway.